# Cannot resolve symbol "EnableWebFluxSecurity" in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, dependencies, spring-webflux, pom.xml

[image]
I am getting not resolved error in
@EnableWebFluxSecurity,
springSecurityFilterChain,
.csrf(),
ServerHttpSecurity &
.pathMatchers()

These are dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: with the code provided this is non reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest version of spring boot 3.1.1 **@EnableWebFluxSecurity, springSecurityFilterChain, .csrf(), ServerHttpSecurity & .pathMatchers()** are deprecated so you have to change the code.

You can refer this code if you are using spring boot 3 :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;


    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeRequests().
            requestMatchers("/category/add")
            .authenticated()
            .requestMatchers("/authenticate","/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(point))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new CustomAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

CustomAuthentcationManager :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return authenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
    }
}
```